# Why does the dictionary not have a gender for "часы"

Tags: существительные, род

It only says it is a noun and in singular number.

Comment: Could you please name this dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is not a singular, but so called 'pluralia tantum', or nouns normally used in plural (e.g. like English 'news').

The paradigm for this type of declension is the same as for plural of час/часы (= hour/hours).

Answer (score 5):

Because it is a plural form and is only used as such. For example, 'one clock' would be *одни часы* in Russian. Similar words are *ножницы*, *сани*, *колготки* etc.

Comment: Sorry, the word **колготы** is unofficial and vernacular Russian (i.e. in the dictionaries it is not mentioned ). [other forum link](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=5b8706464e7bc79b) I would suggest replacing it by **колготки**.

Comment: But I like your answer =)

Comment: @Unari even if word is vernacular, it, generally speaking, does not matter that it is not mentioned in dictionaries ;)

Comment: oh yes @shabunc, my comment lacks logic. =) I should have used conjunction, not equivalence here.

Comment: @Umari It never appeared to me that the normal form was колготки. Although колготы is available on gramota.ru, I have changed it in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Umari Some more elaboration on the topic: http://www.caretta-shop.ru/statall/19/stat58/

Answer (score 2):

Quassnoi is right asking what dictionary doesn't have the gender mark for the word часы. For example, [wikidictionary](http://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B) specifies that the gender is *masculine* as well as it specifies that the word is only used in plural.

Other dictionaries, which I checked, for example Щерба, Матусевич. Русско-французский словарь, 1993, only specify *plural*, and no gender for часы.

Not specifying gender for the words that are only used in plural makes sense for Russian language because their gender has only historical value and does not manifests itself grammatically in any way. In Russian neither endings of adjectives, nor endings of verbs will differ when they are related to plural nouns of different genders. Compare with French which differentiates gender in plural via adjective endings:

> palissades **vertes** (fem.) - зелёные заборы
>
> feux **verts** (masc.) - зелёные огни

Comment: At the time, Russian differentiated gender in some pl. forms too. http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/941/%D0%92%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-or-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%8F-in-old-orthography