# Колготки or колготы?

Tags: выбор-слова, словарь, стилистика

There was a small [discussion](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1768) between [texnic](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/47/texnic) and me about the appropriate way to denote tights - a classical question on forums related to Russian linguistics. As I do not consider myself an expert in Russian language, I would like to ask the community for their opinion, *preferably documented*. Maybe I was wrong?

So my reasons to prefer **колготки** over  **колготы** are:

- **childhood stereotypes**: at school I was taught that the word **колготы** doesn't exist; however, sad experience showed me later that not every teacher knows their matter perfectly;
- **stylistical prejudices**: in my family and kindergarden (yes, again childhood =) )this word was used frequently, but with different stress - **колготЫ** (sometimes even **колготУшки** to rhyme with my name); this gave it а vernacular and stylistically colloquial tone - just like it happens with "inner" words that are made up inside a family and don't sound appropriate when you pronounce them in public;
- **frequency in dictionaries**: as I am not a linguist, I mostly refer to dictionaries written by Ожегов, Ушаков, or Даль (the latter certainly doesn't fit for this question). None of them shows the word колготы; **maybe somebody here has the Big Academic Dictionary?** On the internet while searching for occurence in dictionaries I have also found [this](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=5b8706464e7bc79b&pli=1), **while texnic found opposite information (i.e. this word [*can*](http://www.caretta-shop.ru/statall/19/stat58/) be found in modern dictionaries)**;
- Google and StackExchange underline колготы with red;

If I come up with more arguments, I'll add them.

Well, to sum it up, is this strange word **колготы**:

- dependent on geographical/cultural/demographic aspects;
- stylistically neutral;
- a common grammatical mistake that almost turned into a norm (like infamous **coffee** gender or stress in **заиндевелый**, **фольга** );
- absolutely wrong (like **сосули** instead of **сосульки**);
- just another topic where linguists can't come to a consensus?

Comment: Don't take it too severe, but I have a rhyme for you, about Goths (Ru. Готы):

Гóты, гóты,
На руках
Колгóты.

Comment: A good musing about `сосули` and similar words can be found [here](http://warlen.livejournal.com/90236.html).

Comment: Hehe, @farfareast, I know this poem as I am from Saint-Petersburg =) A good example of how state authorities think they can do **anything** with our language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked my mother. Yes, it turned out to be that simple =) After all she graduated from  [The Herzen University](http://www.herzen.spb.ru) and Russian language  was her specialization.

**Kолготы** is a wrong form, often shows lack of culture and/or education. And this is my final decision.

If anybody needs more proof, I can also mention that - long ago - in some comment a person that I respect very much (professor of biblical studies at the Saint Petersburg State University **Татьяна Ткачeва**) noted that this word is not correct.

Колготы, марш к сосулям!

Answer (score 5):

Хотя "колготки" имеют больше сторонников в академических кругах, "колготы" не должны отчаиваться. Возникновение страшных "ботин" и "перчат" уже много раз увенчивалось успехом и образованные таким образом слова прочно входили в литературный язык.

Такова история слов "зонт" и "фляга". Зонт пришел в русский язык как "зонтик" (нем. sonnetag), фляга как "фляшка" (польск.). Со временем окончания этих слов были переосмыслены как уменьшительные суффиксы и были созданы несуществовавшие "фляга" и "зонт".

Кстати о "сосулях". Поищите в Национальном корпусе сосули - будете удивлены. Примеров не много, но когда-то их употребляли Набоков, Горький и Андрей Белый в обычном, не комическом смысле.

Вот Набоков:

> Песком, будто рыжей корицей, усыпан был ледок, облепивший ступени крыльца, а с выступа крыши, остриями вниз, свисали толстые сосули, сквозящие зеленоватой синевой. [В. В. Набоков. Рождество (1925)]

Максим Горький:

> Уже была пятница страстной недели, а капель к ночи намерзала синими сосулями в пол-аршина длиною; лед на реке, оголенной от снега, тоже был синеватый, как зимние облака. [Максим Горький. Ледоход (1912-1915)]

Answer (score 3):

A brief search of the [national corpus](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/en/search-main.html) shows that the word "колготы" has been used as a genitive of "колгота" (a synonym of "суета") until the eighties, when the meaning of "колготы" as a synonym of "колготки" started to appear:

> А для той колготы и начальников много понаставили. (1924)
>
> Кстати, черные, темные чулки (или колготы) не худят полных ног. (1988)

The word "колготки" has appeared in the corpus more than a decade earlier, so your teacher was right: for a while, only "колготки" was a real word, and "колготы" did not exist.

Here are the search results:

- [Колготы](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&t=100&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&req=%EA%EE%EB%E3%EE%F2%FB&lang=ru&p=1) - [(distribution by year)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&t=100&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&req=%EA%EE%EB%E3%EE%F2%FB&lang=ru&p=1)
- [Колготки](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&t=100&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=en&req=%EA%EE%EB%E3%EE%F2%EA%E8) - [(distribution by year)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&t=100&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&req=%EA%EE%EB%E3%EE%F2%EA%E8&lang=ru)

Comment: Wow, this national corpus is such a good resource!  Thanks for giving a link!

Comment: Your answer is great! I'll just wait a bit more for other responds, but so far I am ready to accept it. =)

Comment: @Umari: The answer is good and it shows interesting aspect but it does not make a final statement if колготы is a fine word *now* or is it a dialect.

Comment: @farfareast, I don't think it could be a dialect. I mentioned geography only because I wanted to get info about it in the answers (e.g. "I'm from Moscow and we speak so") - curiosity. The question is more about whether it is a neutral word, a  common grammatical mistake almost turning into norm (like that with coffee or stress in заиндеветь), a colloquial word, or probably it is absolutely   wrong (like the word сосули instead of сосульки).

Comment: I edited the question so that it is clearer what I am actually asking.